# Who was this (possibly DC Comics) female character that was a daughter of Satan, or some demon

Tags: dc, character-identification

This female character was in - if I remember correctly, DC Comics - comic book I read in the 80's. She was described as the daughter of "Satan" (or some similar evil being) and had an ability to absorb other people's suffering.

She did not have horns or any other "classic Devil" physical attributes and was more of a good person (not a villainess). Generally speaking she looked like a typical comic book chick although I think she had no irises (her eyeballs were all white).

Before coming to earth, she had been on a planet that was ruled over (or should I say, victimized) by her father.

Comment: Was it Raven? http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Raven

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might be talking about [Raven](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Raven), daughter of Trigon and famous as a member of the Teen Titans.

[image: Textless cover of Raven Daughter of Darkness Vol 1 1, featuring Raven]

Answer (score -2):

I know who you're talking about but its not Raven. She looks like Silver Banshee mostly, but I remember she has a sword as well and two hound pets.

Lady Death is the answer

Comment: The only "Lady Death" I know of is [the one created by Brian Pulido](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lady_Death). There's just plain [Death](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_(DC_Comics)) of the Endless, but she never had a sword. "Hound pets" sounds more like a [Harley Quinn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harley_Quinn) thing; if so, they were hyenas, actually. In short - I don't think you're right, and wouldn't even if the "Raven" answer wasn't accepted.

Comment: This answer is also correct, even if it was not what the OP was thinking of. Googling "comic books daughter of satan" leads hear, and Lady Death almost entirely matches the OP's question. Lady Death is the daughter of Lucifer (another name for Satan in many interpretations of Christianity), she has white eyes, and while she doesn't come from another planet, she does leave earth and travel to hell.

Also just to correct @RDFozz, Lady Death's pets were indeed "hounds". Specifically, referred to as the "nameless wolves" in the 2004 animated movie "Lady Death".